# Firestore collection data not displaying in recycler view but it is accessed correctly

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

As described in the title, I have a firestore collection with two documents which I want to show in my recycler View. I can see in logs that data is accessed correctly and my recycler view adapter size also shows correct number but recycler view does not show up. I thought it might be due to me using view binding but I doubt that is the issue. I am out of ideas, any help is appreciated!

**This is my RecyclerView adapter:**

```
    open class BoardItemsAdapter(private val context: Context, private val list: ArrayList<Board>): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    private var boardItemClickListener: BoardItemClickInterface? = null;


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        val binding = ItemBoardBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false);

        return MyViewHolder(binding);
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val model = list[position];

        if(holder is MyViewHolder){
            Glide.with(context)
                .load(model.image)
                .centerCrop()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_board_place_holder)
                .into(holder.binding.ivBoardImageItemBoard);

            holder.binding.tvNameItemBoard.text = model.name;
            holder.binding.tvCreatedByItemBoard.text = "Created by: ${model.createdBy}";


            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                if(boardItemClickListener != null){
                    boardItemClickListener!!.onClick(position, model);
                }
            }

        }

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size;

    }

    inner class MyViewHolder(val binding:ItemBoardBinding):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){
    }

}
```

**A snippet of FirestoreClass**

```
fun getBoardsList(activity: MainActivity){
    mFirestore.collection(Constants.BOARDS)
        .whereArrayContains(Constants.ASSIGNED_TO,getCurrentUserID())
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            document ->
            Log.i(activity.javaClass.simpleName, document.documents.toString()); //logs correct data
            val boardList: ArrayList<Board> = ArrayList();

            for(i in document.documents){
                val board = i.toObject(Board::class.java)!!;
                board.documentID = i.id;
                boardList.add(board)

            }

            activity.populateBoardsListToUI(boardList);                 

        }.addOnFailureListener {
            e ->
            activity.hideProgressDialog();
            Log.e(activity.javaClass.simpleName,"Error while creatng a board",e);
        }
}
```

**A snippet of MainActivity:**

```
fun populateBoardsListToUI(boardsList: ArrayList<Board>){

    mainContentBinding = MainContentBinding.inflate(layoutInflater);
    hideProgressDialog();

    if(boardsList.size > 0){
        mainContentBinding.rvBoards.visibility = View.VISIBLE;
        mainContentBinding.tvNoBoardsAvailable.visibility = View.GONE;

        mainContentBinding.rvBoards.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mainContentBinding.rvBoards.setHasFixedSize(true);

        val adapter = BoardItemsAdapter(this@MainActivity, boardsList);
        mainContentBinding.rvBoards.adapter = adapter;
        Log.i("POPUI","Board adapter size: ${adapter.itemCount}");
        
    }

    else{
        mainContentBinding.rvBoards.visibility = View.GONE;
        mainContentBinding.tvNoBoardsAvailable.visibility = View.VISIBLE;
    }

}
```

**MainContent.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/main_screen_content_padding"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:elevation="@dimen/card_view_elevation"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_view_corner_radius"
        >


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_boards"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_no_boards_available"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/no_boards_available"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/no_boards_available_text_size"
            />

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Board class**

```
    import android.os.Parcel
import android.os.Parcelable
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parceler
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize


@Parcelize
data class Board(
    val name: String = "",
    val image : String = "",
    val createdBy: String = "",
    val assignedTo: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList(),
    var documentID: String = ""

): Parcelable{
    constructor(parcel: Parcel): this(
        parcel.readString()!!,
        parcel.readString()!!,
        parcel.readString()!!,
        parcel.createStringArrayList()!!,
        parcel.readString()!!
    )

    override fun describeContents() = 0

    companion object : Parceler<Board> {
        override fun Board.write(dest: Parcel, flags: Int) = with(dest) {
           writeString(name);
           writeString(image);
           writeString(createdBy);
           writeStringList(assignedTo);
            writeString(documentID);
        }

        override fun create(parcel: Parcel): Board = TODO()
    }

}
```

**Database screenshot**
[Database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PduYw.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get value from pushed data in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67688456/how-to-get-value-from-pushed-data-in-firebase)

Comment: @androidLearner As far as I can see the adapter is already created from `addOnSuccessListener`, which is the equivalent of `onDataChange` in your linked answer. Can you clarify why you think this is a duplicate?

Comment: because he is passing activity to firestore class then once he got document he is calling activity method to populate recyclerview.so i believe ,instead of firestore class he can call firestore instance from activity itself.so i thought , if he see that question and answer he would get better idea from that.if i am wrong please correct me.@FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Thank you for your answers! @androidLearner I see what you mean but I am using my FirestoreClass as a place where all methods dealing with accessing or creating data in firestore are written. That way if I ever need to change something i know it is in one place, I dont have to track down in which class I called the method to change. That is the reason I'm not calling the firestore instance directly in activity.

Comment: Yes.your intention is correct.but you can not get data if you pass whole activity in Async method.so what i would recommend,  if you know about architecture component, you can use repository class for all database access code .once you got data from database use mutable live data to send data to activity .use observer concept to get live data out of  firestore callback. @Perooo1

Comment: I must admit I am more or less a beginner, only having 4 apps created and this being first one using firestore. I'm not too familiar with arhitecture components but I see there is a lot of documentation so I'll be looking it up. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: You are totally welcome!@Perooo1

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and please also add the content of your "Board" class.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have edited the question, hopefully it's a bit more clear now.