# Why the chat list is not appearing?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

It is like social media app,This fragment should display the chat list, But it isn't, Here is the codes:

DirectMessagesFragment:

```
public class DirectMessagesFragment extends Fragment{
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
FirebaseUser currentUser;
AdapterChatlist adapterChatlist;
DatabaseReference ref;
RecyclerView recyclerViewChatter;
List<ModelChatter> chatterList ;
List<ModelChatlist> chatlistList ;

public DirectMessagesFragment(){}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_direct_messages, container, false);
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    recyclerViewChatter = view.findViewById(R.id.chatter_recyclerview);
    chatlistList = new ArrayList<>();

    ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chatlist").child(currentUser.getUid());
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            chatlistList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot ds:snapshot.getChildren()){
                ModelChatlist chatlist = ds.getValue(ModelChatlist.class);
                chatlistList.add(chatlist);}
            loadChats();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {}
    });
    return view;
}


private void loadChats() {
    chatterList = new ArrayList<>();
    ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            chatterList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot ds:snapshot.getChildren()){
                ModelChatter chatter = ds.getValue(ModelChatter.class);
                for(ModelChatlist chatlist: chatlistList){
                    if(chatter.getUid() != null && chatter.getUid().equals(chatlist.getId())){
                        chatterList.add(chatter);
                        break;
                    }}
                adapterChatlist = new AdapterChatlist(getContext(), chatterList);
                recyclerViewChatter.setAdapter(adapterChatlist);
            }}

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {}
    });
}}
```

In ChatActivity:

```
        //create chat list in firebase
        DatabaseReference ref1 = 
   FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ChatList")
                .child(uid).child(hisUid);
        ref1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if(!snapshot.exists()){
                    ref1.child("id").setValue(hisUid);
                }}

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {}
        });
        DatabaseReference ref2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ChatList")
                .child(hisUid).child(uid);
        ref2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if(!snapshot.exists()){
                    ref2.child("id").setValue(uid);
                }}            
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {}
        });}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
};
/////////
}
```

ModelChatlist only contain id.

ModelChatter contain name, image, uid.

AdapterChatlist:

```
public class AdapterChatlist extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterChatlist.MyHolder>{
Context context;
List<ModelChatter> chattersList;

public AdapterChatlist(Context context, List<ModelChatter> chattersList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.chattersList = chattersList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_dm, parent, false);
    return new MyHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder holder, int position) {
    String userImage = chattersList.get(position).getImage();
    String userName = chattersList.get(position).getName();
    String hisUid = chattersList.get(position).getUid();


    holder.chatter_name.setText(userName);
    try {
        Picasso.with(context).load(userImage).placeholder(R.drawable.user).into(holder.chatter_img);
    } catch (Exception e){
        Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.user).into(holder.chatter_img);

    }

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChatActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("hisUid", hisUid);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return chattersList.size();}

class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView chatter_img;
    TextView chatter_name;
    public MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        chatter_img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chatter_img);
        chatter_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chatter_name);
    }}}}
```

fragment_direct_messages layout contain the recyclerview, row_dm contain the cardview

Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **400 (four hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Answer (score 0):

Pass chat list into your method

```
 for (DataSnapshot ds:snapshot.getChildren()){
                ModelChatlist chatlist = ds.getValue(ModelChatlist.class);
                chatlistList.add(chatlist);
            }
            loadChats(chatlistList);



private void loadChats(List<ModelChatlist> chatlist) {

//your code
}
```

Comment: Nothing has changed, thank you for trying

Comment: so did you check chatlistList size after added the value from snapshot? outside for loop@SalmaSaloom

Comment: Instead of ds.getValue use ,ds.toObject(yourModelClass)

Comment: toObject is undefined (red color)

Comment: Oops!Look at here(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67688456/how-to-get-value-from-pushed-data-in-firebase/67689440#67689440) to get value from datasnapshot.@SalmaSaloom

Answer (score 0):

Try adding filters (like logging the data received) to check where the actual problem persists. It's difficult to go through so much code.